# Spark-Eventstoredb connect

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, event-driven-design, eventstoredb

I'm working on handling events coming from eventstoredb using spark put actually couldn't find a straightforward way to connect between them with pyspark.
What I aim to do is to read events as stream with spark and do some logic on them or maybe read them as patch what is the standard way to do this.

Already searched on connectors or any relation between both tools but couldn't find any. I expect to make something similar how spark connect with kafka and read streams of events.

If you have any techniques or best practices on this topic it would be appreciated to share.

Comment: might be worth going to their discord?

Comment: There's nothing ready-made indeed, but it's relatively straightforward. As Ruben mentioned, if you come to Event Store Discord server, there are people there who can help.